Shortest way to cause a seg fault at 0x9c?
In honour of CrowdStrike's exception at 0x9c, what's the shortest way (character-wise) to cause a segfault by dereferencing address 0x9c?
The best I can come up with is:
int main(){*(int*)156=0;}
Rules:

It must be valid C++ (so no removing the return type int of main)
It must crash the program


Please note that asking for malicious code is forbidden (there may be a more relevant post on meta -- didn't find it). That said, I would not say that a seg fault really counts as malicious code. It's just a bit borderline.

Shortening it would be difficult, but for only one extra character you can disguise it ;) int main(){39[(int*)0]=0;}: Try it online See assembly
